# Colocar arquivo de audio para download e ouvir em php

Tags: php, download, html5-audio, áudio

Tenho alguns áudios no meu servidor e desejo colocá-los online para que seja possível o lado cliente ter acesso, tanto para ouvir e fazer download. estou trabalhando com php e um servidor linux, uma versão do debian.

```
<td> 
        <audio controls="controls">
             <source src="teste.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
         </audio>
  </td>
```

esse é um exemplo encontrado na internet, porém quando eu coloco o caminho do meu arquivo não consigo acessá-lo, tanto para baixar ou ouvir.

Então, qual é a melhor forma para poder fazer download e ouvir online um arquivo wav do meu servidor em uma aplicação online

Answer (score 1):

```
<td> 
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="teste.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</td>
<br />
<a href='forcardownload.php?arquivo=teste.mp3'>Baixar MP3</a>
```

Dê uma lida de como criar um script de forçar download de arquivos: [AQUI](http://www.phpit.com.br/artigos/forcar-o-download-de-um-arquivo-melhorado-e-bug-corrigido.phpit)

> Obs: Fique atento nas questões de segurança no texto do link informado.

Comment: Mas por exemplo apenas de eu informar o caminho do arquivo no servidor no campo scr já é possível o lado cliente fazer o download?

Comment: 90% dos navegadores hoje em dia não baixa mais, faz é reproduzir direto no navegador, por isso estou indicando a você o link para criar um script PHP que força o download.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda. vou verificar o link